# task.getResult() returns false while unregistering an OnDataPointListener

Tags: java, android, google-fit-sdk

```
/**
 *  Register fitness listeners for all the required data types
 */
private void registerFitnessListeners() {
    mStepCountListener =
            new OnDataPointListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                    for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()){
                        int stepDelta = dataPoint.getValue(field).asInt();
                        mSteps += stepDelta;
                        stepCountTextView.setText(
                                "Detected Datapoint field: " + field.getName()
                                + "\nDetected Datapoint value:" + mSteps);
                    }
                }
            };

    Fitness.getSensorsClient(mContext, mGoogleSignInAccount)
            .add(
                    new SensorRequest.Builder()
                            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                            .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .setMaxDeliveryLatency(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .setFastestRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .build(),
                    mStepCountListener)
            .addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                Log.d(TAG, "Listener registered");
                            }else{
                                Log.e(TAG, "Listener not registered", task.getException());
                            }
                        }
                    });
}


/**
 * Unregisters the listener with the Sensors API.
 */
private void unregisterFitnessListeners(){
    Fitness.getSensorsClient(mContext, mGoogleSignInAccount)
            .remove(mStepCountListener)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Listener was removed");
                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "Listener was not removed");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

When I try to unregister a OnDataPointListener for counting steps, my LogCat always says listener was not removed. I got to know that task.getResult() is always returning false. Why is this so?? Am I doing something wrong? How can I remove the listener?

Edit : I have created an issue on Google's issue tracker. You can star it so that it gets quickly fixed. Here's the link

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130741650

Comment: i have same problem have get solutions?

Comment: @VanrajGhed, I figured out that the bug was only in the latest version of the google fit api. The old version works correctly. So you can change the version from the one you're using to the one below : 
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:12.0.1'

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing a similar issue but then I tried a way around the `SensorsApi`

```
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = Fitness
                .getSensorsClient(context, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context))
                .asGoogleApiClient();

Fitness.SensorsApi.remove(googleApiClient, mListener).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResult: Successfully removed sensor api");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResult: Unable to remove sensor api");
                }
            }
        });
```

And it works like a charm!

Comment: thank you. I have been struggling with this for days

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the bug was only in the latest version of the google fit sdk. The old version works correctly. So changing the version to the one below worked: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:12.0.1'